# What is the limit of this function?

Tags: limits

$$
f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} 
\left( 1 + \tan x \right) ^{\dfrac{1}{\sin 3x}}
$$
How can i solve it? When I tried to solve this function with $e^{ \lim_{x \to a} \left( f(x) \cdot g(x) \right) }$ formula. I could not find anything because of the fact that tangent has no limit at infinity.

Comment: Are you sure that the question asked for limit to infinity, and not to $0$?  (I'm a bit puzzled on $\to \infty$, because of the lack of a limit for either $\sin$ or $\tan$ at $\infty$...)

Comment: Limit to zero doesn't exist unless I'm misinterpreting the extent of that fraction bar. Perhaps it should be clarified?

Comment: Yeah sure, x goes to infinity but maybe there is a printing error in book.

Comment: Both tan and sin functions are periodic - the periods are rational multiples of $\pi$. Multiplying by $3$ to get $3x$ doesn't change the fact that you have a periodic function with period a rational multiple of $\pi$. So your function is periodic, with period a rational multiple of $\pi$ - and has no limit at infinity unless it is constant.

Comment: A look at a graph of this function ought to convince one:  there are periodic vertical asymptotes and no finite number that the function "approaches arbitrarily closely"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=\frac\pi4+2k\pi$, $\tan x=1$ and $\sin x=1/\sqrt2$, so your expression is $2^{1/\sqrt2}$.

For $x=2k\pi$, $\tan x=0$, so your expression is $1$.

The limit as $x\to\infty$ does not exist.

When $x\to0$: in this case we have
$$
(1 + \tan x )^{1/\sin3x}=\exp\left(\frac{\log(1 + \tan x )}{\sin3x}\right).
$$
Inside the exponential, 
$$
\frac{\log(1 + \tan x )}{\sin3x}= \frac{\tan x}{\sin 3x}+o(x)=\frac{\tan x}x\,\frac13\,\frac1{\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}}+o(x)\to\frac13.
$$
By the continuity of the exponential, the limit is $e^{1/3}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Probably there is a printing error. X has to go zero for solution. Consequently result is $e^{\dfrac{1}{3}}$ as wolframAlpha said.

Comment: Ok. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D+%5Clim_%7Bx+%5Cto+0%7D++%5Cleft%28+1+%2B+%5Ctan+x+%5Cright%29+%5E%7B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csin+3x%7D%7D&x=0&y=0

I used 0 limit. The infinity limit is something else.

Answer (score 0):

The limit has to be zero. Then ${f(x) }$ can solved by applying ${f(x)=e^{ln(f(x))} }$ and expanding ${ sin(3x) , ln(1+tan(x)) }$ . I think this should solve the problem. :)